# mark interrupt as wakeup source on linux?

Tags: c++, linux, interrupt, gpio, intel-edison

I have an embedded board (intel edison) onto which I have a switch connected to an gpio pin. In my c++ code I have registered the gpio as an interrupt. When I call "cat /proc/interrupts" I can see how the counter increments when I press the switch.

How can I make the interrupt wakeup the system if it's in suspend-to-ram state?

Comment: So much time gone... On new kernel there is a new GPIO user space ABI via character device and corresponding IOCTLs.